# Detect the existence of a private key

Tags: winapi

I 'm trying to present the user a dialog to pick a certificate. Originally I used `CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore` with the "MY" store, but this results in picking all the certificates, where I only want the user to select between the 
certificates that have private keys.

For that reason, I create a new memory store and store only the certificates for which a private key exists. I can use `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey` to get a private key of a certificate, but this may result in a dialog box requesting a PIN for example. I don't want to use the `CRYPT_ACQUIRE_SILENT_FLAG` because a provider might want to show information on the key (not necessarily a pin or a smart card prompt).

Is there a way to know that there is a private key *without actually acquiring it*?

Thanks.

Comment: you need call `CertGetCertificateContextProperty` with `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID` if it return true - certificat associated with container where can exist private key. value of *dwKeySpec* - The specification of the private key to retrieve. (*AT_KEYEXCHANGE* or *AT_SIGNATURE*). if certificate have not container association - you got `CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND` error. note that this is not certificate property itself, but when it enum/find from store. also if no provider info this way - can query also `CERT_PVK_FILE_PROP_ID`